# Twilio conference recordingStatusCallback URL not triggering

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml, twimlet

I am using the recordingStatusCallback for conference as stated here https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-recording-status-callback

However, this URL is never been hit at all. I am not able to get the recording, but when I log in to Twilio I so see the actual recording in the console. Any ideas whats going here?

Here is what my TwiML looks like for dialing a conference with recording.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Conference 
            statusCallback="http://myserver.com/dial/conference/statuscallback"
            statusCallbackEvent="start end join leave mute hold" endConferenceOnExit="false" 
            record="record-from-start" recordingStatusCallback="http://myserver.com/conference/recordingstatuscallback"
            recordingStatusCallbackMethod="POST"    
            waitUrl="http://myserver.com/conference/wait">CA109d746665943ef1bf8cdccc8fb30754
        </Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work around is to put the record settings on the Dial instead of the conference. I did this and seems to work good.

Comment: How do you do that with NodeJS? When I do `twiml.dial().conference(recordAttrs, roomId)` how do I move the `recordAttrs` to the dial verb?

Comment: I was able to pass it in the `dial()` but then I got this: `Dial: Invalid record value` and `"record must be true,false,full,all,record-from-answer,record-from-ringing,do-not-record,record-from-answer-dual,record-from-ringing-dual"`

Comment: I tried `"record-from-answer-dual"` next, an this doesn't throw an error anymore, but also doesn't trigger my `recordingStatusCallback` anymore again. Same problem as when it's on the `<Conference>` tag... Any hints? Can I see your working full XML?